# I can't see NAT Network ip when using bridged adapter and nat network within two adapters in VirtualBox

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine

So the title basically summarizes all. I am trying to set up a virtual box machine with two adapters, NAT network and the other bridged. The result is that when I boot the machine and use the "ip addr" command, it shows me both adapters, but the one where the NAT network is configured doesn't show any IP.

Using them separately does work, if I use the NAT network I can see the other machines connected to it and if I use bridged I can connect to the internet, but if I enable both I only can access the Internet, but not the NAT network.

Why does this happen? Is there any fix?

EDIT: The goal of this is to connect a second VM to my main VM while being able to connect to the internet

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to fix it. The thing is that the interfaces file in linux didn't have "registered" the additional interfaces, so I added them.
I did the following:

```
nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

So I found that the content was this:

```
source blablabla

#loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Somehow, without specifyng the interfaces the device was working. In the end of the file I added the following:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

So now both interfaces are working :)